# Recursively filter array of objects problem in return

Tags: reactjs

I have a fixed array like this And a return function to find the desired value. My problem is that even when the submenu is empty, an empty variable returns to the submenu: [] which I do not want

```
const myMenu = {items : [{
  title: "menu 1",
  root: true,
  icon: "flaticon2-architecture-and-city",
  page: "dashboard",
  bullet: "dot",
  MenuId:1,
},
{
  title: "menu 2",
  root: true,
  bullet: "dot",
  icon: "flaticon2-browser-2",
  MenuId:2,
  submenu: [
    {
      title: "sub menu 1",
      bullet: "dot",
      page: "AssetMainPage",
      MenuId:3,

    },
    {
      title: "sub menu 2",
      page: "Departments",
      bullet: "dot",
      MenuId:4,  
    },
  ],
},
{
  title: "menu 3",
  root: true,
  icon: "flaticon2-architecture-and-city",
  page: "dashboard",
  bullet: "dot",
  MenuId:5,
  submenu: [
    {
      title: "sub menu 1",
      page: "AssetMeter",
      MenuId:6,
    },
    {
      title: "sub menu 2",
      page: "ChangeAssetStatus",
      MenuId:7,
    },
    {
      title: "گزارش وضعیت و کارکرد",
      page: "AssetsMeterAndStatusReports",
      MenuId:8,
    },
  ],

},
]}
```

**And I have this Recursively function for find and retrn array :**

```
function filter(arr, term) {
  var matches = [];
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return matches;
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
      if (i.MenuId === term) {
       const filterData =  (i.submenu && Array.isArray(i.submenu))? i.submenu.filter(values => values.MenuId === term):[];
      // console.log(filterData)
       i.submenu =filterData;
          matches.push(i);
      } else {
      //console.log(i.children)
      let childResults = filter(i.submenu, term);
      if (childResults.length ) {  
          matches.push(Object.assign({}, i,{submenu: childResults} ));
      }  
    }
  })
  return matches;
}
```

**My question is whether I can not return that variable at all when the submenu array is empty.
Like the following output:**

```
 // call function 
  const filterData = filter(myMenu.items,7); 
  console.log("filterData",filterData)
```

**i want this result :**

```
  title: "menu 3",
  root: true,
  icon: "flaticon2-architecture-and-city",
  page: "dashboard",
  bullet: "dot",
  MenuId:5,
  submenu :[
      title: "sub menu 2",
      page: "ChangeAssetStatus",
      MenuId:7,
      // exactly here i dont want return empty submenu:[] 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `arr.forEach` function:

```
function filter(arr, term) {
  var matches = [];
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return matches;
  arr.forEach(function (i) {
    if (i.MenuId === term) {
      const filterData =
        i.submenu && Array.isArray(i.submenu)
          ? i.submenu.filter((values) => values.MenuId === term)
          : [];
      // console.log(filterData)
      i.submenu = filterData;
      if (!i.submenu.length) {
        delete i.submenu;
      }
      matches.push(i);
    } else {
      //console.log(i.children)
      let childResults = filter(i.submenu, term);
      if (childResults.length) {
        matches.push(Object.assign({}, i, { submenu: childResults }));
      }
    }
  });
  return matches;
}
```

Comment: It returns all array values does not filter

Comment: Are you sure? This is working for me. I edited the answer copying the entire function. Let me know if it works also for you please.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I filter multiple inputs?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple inputs? Can you explain more please?

Comment: Search multiple numbers from within the array and return multiple results to the same array as before, That is, searching for multiple numbers within that array, not as one

Answer (score 1):

Just before assign value to `submenu` property you can check that `filtedData` is an empty array or not, by checking it's `length` property:

```
...
const filterData = (i.submenu && Array.isArray(i.submenu))? i.submenu.filter(values => values.MenuId === term):[];
if(filterData.length){ i.submenu =filterData; }
...
```